# getting error when groovy run through java

Tags: java, groovy

used groovy and java
i have groovy script used to spit,

```
 def msgO = app.getConversation()
    msgO+=msg.getText()        
    def list = msgO.split("\\+")
```

getting error when 
running with java code :

```
CaptureUtil captureUtil = new CaptureUtil();
            binding.setVariable("cap", captureUtil);    
            GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);    
            boolean status = (boolean) shell.evaluate(template);
```

getting the error :

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2380)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
    at java_lang_String$split.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:20)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at com.ctf.sims.parseutils.CaptureUtil.parseGroovy(CaptureUtil.java:185)
```

when run groovy script it's running well,getting error when run through java only.

Comment: Looks like you need to use pattern '\+' instead of '\\+'.

Comment: when i put '\+' getting eror "startup failed: Script1.groovy: 18: unexpected char: '\' @ line 18, column 28. def list = msgO.split('\+') ^ 1 error"

Comment: Can't reproduce using that code. That error only happens if one doesn't escape the plus sign. And yours is properly escaped.

Comment: i want to do it with that groovy

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
msgO.split(Pattern.quote('+'))
```

Comment: please give me the def code also getting error "No such property: Pattern for class: Script1"

Comment: msgO.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote('+'))

Comment: Tried just now:
`new groovy.lang.GroovyShell().evaluate("'1+2+3'.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote('+')")`

Works fine for me. It's maybe something in the way you creating the Groovy shell from Java.